# jQuery Validation on entire page

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, validation, asp.net-mvc-3

I have a webpage developed in ASP.NET MVC 3 and I am using jQuery validator to validate my fields.

```
  $.validator.setDefaults({
    errorContainer: "#validationSummary, #validationNotice",
    highlight: function (element, errorClass) {
        $(element).css("border", "1px dotted red");
    },
    unhighlight: function (element, errorClass) {
        $(element).css("border", "1px solid black");
    }
});
```

This will give my fields a "red dotted border" when they aren't valid.

I have a text that i want to show IF all fields are valid in my page .

```
        <div class="ReadyToSend" style="margin-top:50px;">
                   All fields are valid.
        </div>
```

So I want to hide "ReadyToSend" if my page isn't valid and show it if ALL of my fields on the page is valid.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try this

```
$.validator.setDefaults({
    errorContainer: "#validationSummary, #validationNotice",
    highlight: function (element, errorClass) {
        $(element).css("border", "1px dotted red");
        $(".ReadyToSend").hide();
    },
    unhighlight: function (element, errorClass) {
        $(element).css("border", "1px solid black");
        if($("#yourFormName").validate().checkForm()) {
            $(".ReadyToSend").show();
        }
    }
});
```

make sure you add `display: none` on your ReadyToSend `div`

Answer (score 0):

> function hidemsg(){
>   document.getElementById('ReadyToSend').style.display='none';}
>   ...  my text

You use the above function by giving a condition to it, hope it will help.

Comment: this does not answer his question.