# Kendo model-based validation in jQuery using span and a class, MVC framework

Tags: jquery, html, css, asp.net-mvc, validation

I'm using Razor MVC and model-binding to enforce validation restrictions, such as StringLength (so they don't enter in more text than my database field length), for example:

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.LastName) <br/>
<span class="errorText" style="right:50px;top:100px">
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.LastName)
</span>
```

And that span controls the formatting of the message using the `errorText` class:

```
<style type="text/css">
    .errorText {
         background-color: red;
         border: 2px solid black;
         margin: 2px;
         color: white;
         font-size: 13px;
         position: absolute;
         z-index: 100;
    }
</style>
```

I control where the validation message appears via its `top` and `right` properties on the span.

The problem is these spans will show little black blocks on the page if they have no text, and I want to hide those unless a message needs to be shown.  Is there a way to hide the spans until a message needs to appear, and then show them?  And then hide them again when the condition clears?

Tried

```
.on('change', function() { ... } )
```

to see if it would fire and

```
    $('[class="errorText"]').each(function() {
        $(this).bind('blur', function() {
            $(this).css('border','0px');
        });
    }
```

The `change` and `blur` events don't get called because the span never gets focused or blurred.  I've seen sites saying to do `.removeClass()` (take off errorText) and `.addClass()` (put on a class with `display:none`), but how do I do that when I can't bind to an event?  Is there another way?  Do I just repeatedly check the spans for their `.html()`?  I have many fields on this page, so it seems too memory-intensive and I'm looking for alternatives.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I figured out how to do it from another, related thread:
[jQuery Validation on entire page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5039173/jquery-validation-on-entire-page?rq=1)

The HTML, when rendered, looked like this:

```
<INPUT id=LastName class=k-textbox value=asdf type=text name=LastName data-val="true" data-val-length-max="50" data-val-length="The field Last Name must be a string with a maximum length of 50."><BR>
<SPAN style="TOP:100px;RIGHT:50px" class="errorText">
    <SPAN class="field-validation-valid" data-valmsg-replace="true" data-valmsg-for="LastName"></SPAN>
</SPAN>
```

I was able to take advantage of that HTML by first removing the border, and padding I later added, to 0px, and since the "element" in the function below is the "INPUT" above, I did this to alter the validation message span:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('[class="errorText"]').css("border", "0px solid white").padding("0px");
});

$.validator.setDefaults({
    errorContainer: "#field-validation-valid",
    highlight: function (element, errorText) {
        $(element).parent().children(1).children(0).css("border", "3px solid black").padding("5px");
    },
    unhighlight: function (element, errorText) {
        $(element).parent().children(1).children(0).css("border", "0px solid white").padding("0px");
    }
});
```

and I changed the CSS a little:

```
<style type="text/css">
    .errorText {
         font-size: 13px;
         color: white;
         height: 27px;
         margin: 2px;
         background-color: red;
         position: absolute;
         z-index: 100;
    }
</style>
```

I removed the border and padding from the class, since it was going to be applied and removed on-the-fly using the jQuery validator "highlight" and "unhighlight" events, anyway.